# Return id from Typeorm raw Update query

Tags: sql, typescript, typeorm, raw

How can I return Id and other fields of rows that were updated for a Update raw query in typeorm?

Here's my query

```
const slots = await manager.query(`
        UPDATE slot
        SET status = 'void', void_reason = 'Billing - incomplete verification'
        WHERE start_date > NOW() - INTERVAL '1 days'
        AND status = 'void'
      `)
```